# How to Calculate Sum of a Column in a SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm developing a leave system using Sharepoint 2010 and I have stored following data on a sharepoint list.

**Applied Days         3   ,   5          ....................

Sum of Applied Days            3   ,   8 (Can't get this values)

Remaining Days                 x    ,  x**

For calculate Remaining Leave days I need to count sum of applied days. but i can't get the cumulative value of applied days. there is no formula calculate All Applied Days(or Current Applied Days + previous Sum of Applied Days).  so simply what I need to do is get the sum of a column value.

Is there any method to do this in sharepoint 2010??

Comment: More detail of your solution is needed to be able to help.  Are you storing each leave request as a new item in the list?  Does each person have their own list or are all the leave requests mixed up together?  If everything is in a single item for each user then the calculated column suggested below is good.  If not then you will probably need to work with XSL and XPath to get the totals you need.

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated column and set the return type as Number. I assume the name of the column is `SumOfDaysColumn`.

In Additional Column Settings>Formula:

```
[SumOfDaysColumn] = [AppliedDaysColumn] + [PreviousDaysColumn]
```